# make/makefile: realize that there is a new (not changed) source file

Tags: compilation, makefile

In general my makefile works. Since people will ask, here it is for reference:

```
HEADERS = *.h
OBJS =  *.o
MYFORWARDS = *.c
WARNS = -Wall
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -mwindows -Wall 
LDFLAGS = -mwindows -lkernel32 -luser32
all : my.exe
my.exe : ${OBJS}
    ${CC} -o "$@" ${OBJS} ${LDFLAGS}
%.o : %.c ${HEADERS}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@
```

I like the `*.o` and `*.c` so i dont have to edit the makefile each time a **.c** is added.

Make generally works backwards: For each target look if one of its sources changed, if so rebuild.

I dont want to change that since it's the whole point of make, however there's an exception.

The **problem** is, that when i create a new **.c** file then there exists no **.o** file yet and thus (make working backwards from the **.o**'s) it does not even realize that there is a new **.c**.

What i have done up to now is each time i create a new **.c** i manually create the new **.o** file.

Is there a better way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach is to list out your object files, instead of relying on wildcards.

```
OBJS = main.o util.o something_else.o
```

In GNU Make, you can also use functions, as described in [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function), to make a list of `.o` based on `.c`:

```
OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
```